# How do I swap a subset of values in one column, but leave other values in the same column unchanged?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data.frame called `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(
   A = 1:8, 
   B = rep(letters[1:4], each = 2),
   C = rep(1:2, 4)
)

  A B C
1 1 a 1
2 2 a 2
3 3 b 1
4 4 b 2
5 5 c 1
6 6 c 2
7 7 d 1
8 8 d 2
```

I want to swap the values in column `B`, when they are `b` or `c`, but not when they are `a` or `d`, conditioned on another column `C`, i.e., when `C = 1`. So the target data.frame is `df1`:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(
  A = 1:8,
  B = c("a", "a", "c", "b", "b", "c", "d", "c"),
  C = rep(1:2, 4)      
)

  A B C
1 1 a 1
2 2 a 2
3 3 c 1
4 4 b 2
5 5 b 1
6 6 c 2
7 7 d 1
8 8 c 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr` provides `recode` to replace multiple values at once as shown below. Based on the new requirement in your question, I have updated the code below to provide with desired output:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df
  A B C
1 1 a 1
2 2 a 2
3 3 b 1
4 4 b 2
5 5 c 1
6 6 c 2
7 7 d 1
8 8 d 2

> for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   if(df$C[i] == "1") {
     df$B[i] <- recode(df$B[i], 'b' = 'c', 'c' = 'b')
   }
 }

> df
  A B C
1 1 a 1
2 2 a 2
3 3 c 1
4 4 b 2
5 5 b 1
6 6 c 2
7 7 d 1
8 8 d 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I wondering how this solution could be extended to the a new situation where the swap should be conditioned on another column, column "C"? This is illustrated in my updated question.

Comment: @LikanZhan - I have updated my code. Per my knowledge, `recode` doesn't have any provision to provide a clause within. So, I have added a `for` loop to take care of the new condition. 

NOTE: Your output shows last row (Column `B`) changed to `'c'`; whereas it should stay `'d'`

Comment: @LikanZhan If you want to extend your question after answers have been posted, you should make sure every answerer is okay with it, and if not, instead ask a new question. Your edit invalidated Sotos' answer, for example; which is considered poor etiquette, or at best an avoidable inconvenience, here.

Answer (score 6):

You can try `chartr`,

```
chartr('bc', 'cb', df$B)
#[1] "a" "a" "c" "c" "b" "b" "d" "d"
```

To condition it on `C == 1` then,

```
df$B[df$C == 1] <- chartr('bc', 'cb', df$B[df$C == 1])
```

Comment: The solution does not match the expected given. Check out

Comment: @Onyambu thanks for geting my attention. Obviously the question was updated with new requirements. I will revise tomorrow.

Comment: @Onyambu `df$B <- as.character(df$B); with(df, ifelse(C == 1, chartr("bc", "cb", B), B))` seems to work fine?

Answer (score 2):

```
# this will work generally
ic <- df$B == 'c'
ib <- df$B == 'b'
df$B[ic] <- 'b'
df$B[ib] <- 'c'

> df
  A B
1 1 a
2 2 a
3 3 c
4 4 c
5 5 b
6 6 b
7 7 d
8 8 d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub("_", "", ifelse(df$B == "b", "_c", ifelse(df$B == "c", "_b", as.character(df$B))))
#[1] "a" "a" "c" "c" "b" "b" "d" "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 a=which(df$B%in%letters[2:3]&df$C==1)
 df[a,2]=df[rev(a),2];df
   A B C
 1 1 a 1
 2 2 a 2
 3 3 c 1
 4 4 b 2
 5 5 b 1
 6 6 c 2
 7 7 d 1
 8 8 d 2
```

Comment: Could you give us an explanation?

Comment: just look for the positions where `B` has `b` and `c` while `C==1` then swap them. That's what I did